# How to clear selected tags using flutter_tagging?

Tags: flutter

I need to use tags in my application. For this, I found the flutter_tagging library. My problem is that I do not know how to clear the selected tags when I click on the button.

```
FlutterTagging(
     textFieldDecoration: InputDecoration(
         border: OutlineInputBorder(),
         hintText: "Tags",
         labelText: "Enter tags"),
     addButtonWidget: _buildAddButton(),
     chipsColor: Colors.pinkAccent,
     chipsFontColor: Colors.white,
     deleteIcon: Icon(Icons.cancel,color: Colors.white),
     chipsPadding: EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
     chipsFontSize: 14.0,
     chipsSpacing: 5.0,
     chipsFontFamily: 'helvetica_neue_light',
     suggestionsCallback: (pattern) async {
       return await TagSearchService.getSuggestions(pattern);
       },
     onChanged: (result) {
       setState(() {
         text = result.toString();
         });
       },
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I see two options here:

1. Fork library and add method that will clear `Map _selectedTagValues` variable.
2. Initiate `Key taggingKey = UniqueKey()` ([UniqueKey](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/UniqueKey-class.html)) in your widget, pass it to `FlutterTagging` and call `key.currentState.reset()` when you have to reset it and rebuild whole FlutterTagging widget with their initial state.

Comment: How I can pass key to FlutterTagging?

Comment: By forking library